# modify sysfs thermal trip points

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, sysfs

I'd like to modify [thermal trip points](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/thermal/thermal.txt) on linux sysfs because it is set to a low value. I'v read [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/198276/modify-thermal-trip-points) that you cannot modify critical trip point to avoid serious damages but here I am going to modify a passive trip point. I tried to modify `/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/trip_point_0_temp` with vim but I got:

`"trip_point_0_temp" E667: Fsync failed`.

So I tried echo with `echo 95000 | sudo dd of=/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/trip_point_0_temp` which failed:

`dd: error writing '/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/trip_point_0_temp': Invalid argument
0+1 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes copied, 0.00354233 s, 0.0 kB/s`

Any idea about how to change trip points? do I need to recompile the kernel to change them or I can change them at run-time? I am using [nxp imx6 solo](http://www.nxp.com/products/microcontrollers-and-processors/arm-processors/i.mx-applications-processors/i.mx-6-processors/i.mx-6solo-processors-single-core-multimedia-3d-graphics-arm-cortex-a9-core:i.MX6S) so if modifying trip points is outside the linux and kernel hands, should I ask the hardware producer to change these values for me or there are other ways?

Answer (score 4):

First of all 95 degrees Celsius is a dangerous value, especially with embedded appliances.

The proper way of writing sysfs value might be using the shell's output redirecting feature, with POSIX-like and Bash and as root, it is:

`sudo sh -c 'echo *content* >sysfs_file'`

The last, yes, the manufacturer can decide if the trip point is modifiable if   they want, asking them is the direct method to know what you can and cannot do with the hardware.